# AT&T carrier network slowdown when i logout of ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I am getting an strange "Network failure error" (its trying some time then failed) in AT&T carrier only while logout of the app.

In Logout I have written,

```
[[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
[DSUserDefaults setUser:nil];
[DSSharedPersistance setJobTitleId:NULL];
[DSSharedPersistance setJobTypeId:NULL];
[DSSharedPersistance setCompanyId:NULL];
[DSSharedPersistance setCompanyLocation:NULL];
[DSUserDefaults countryCode:nil];

APP_DELEGATE.arySocialFBFriends=nil;
APP_DELEGATE.arraySocialLDFriends=nil;
```

Here, I have tried with removing of facebook close code also. Even, I did not get success.  Apps is working fine in all cases, the issue is getting only after user logout of the app. (In logout works fine)

When we try login again, it takes some time to connect webservice and finally got failure. 
We are using AWS (Amazon Web Service) for login and all. After logout, we can't enable to login anytime. It would have been working only connecting via WIFI only.

But when try this 10 times, 1 time app is getting to login. Apps is working fine in Debug mode of app also in Xcode connecting with iPhone. There is no problem in any other iPhone. Only AT&T is having problem.

I have tried with increase of session time out of Rest Service. but nothing had worked.